# How to resolve MAC OS _XOPEN_SOURCE error in Xcode while compiling?

Tags: iphone

I am developing application for .Epub extension file reader.I have source code available.
But while compiling the code i am getting below error :

```
#error The deprecated ucontext routines require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined
```

I have gone through the internet for different kind of help, but not able to find exact solution.

Can anybody having any idea which kind of error it is?

How to resolve the above error in Xcode ?

please help out with any resolution for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a pre-processor define to your build command line (`-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` for instance). Do this through your IDE's project properties, or by editing your makefile/changing your compiler flag environment variables.

Alternatively, add:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
```

**before** anything includes standard headers in your code.

Comment: Check this page to see what _XOPEN_SOURCE does and what values you can set it to: http://man.he.net/man7/feature_test_macros

Answer (score 2):

Afterwards MAC os 10.6, you need to include "sys/ucontext.h" instead of just "ucontext.h" then you'll not need pre-processor include for _XOPEN_SOURCE.